# Autorotate not working after reload view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, reload, autorotate

I'm trying to make an iPhone app, but i found some issue that auto-rotate is not working after I reload the view controller.
here is the code for loading the app for first run:

```
//AppDelegate.m:<br />
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    iPhoneScanViewController = [[iPhoneScan alloc] init];
    iPhoneScanViewController.ENAD = self;
    [window addSubview:iPhoneScanViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

the view controller loads, autorotate is working.
then sometimes I need to reload the view controller, this is what I use:

```
-(void) resetIphoneScan {
    if (iPhoneScanViewController) {
        [iPhoneScanViewController release];
    }
    iPhoneScanViewController = [[iPhoneScan alloc] init];
    iPhoneScanViewController.ENAD = self;

    for (UIView *view in [window subviews])
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [window addSubview:iPhoneScanViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

After I reload / resetIphoneScan, the autorotate won't work. I've spend a few days on this problem and I haven't found solution for that. I really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that rather than reload the entire root VC, you have separate data classes which you can reset as necessary - after all, the VC is really for displaying it all.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, that's exackly what I do, and it seems to be working ^^